# Make Fyne popup menu appear at mouse position

Tags: go, fyne

I'm stuck at getting the position of the mouse. I want to show the Fyne popup menu at the position of the mouse but can't figure it out.

Here's how I use the popup:

```golang
menuItem1 := fyne.NewMenuItem("A", nil)
menuItem2 := fyne.NewMenuItem("B", nil)
menuItem3 := fyne.NewMenuItem("C", nil)
menu := fyne.NewMenu("File", menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3)

popUpMenu := widget.NewPopUpMenu(menu, window.Canvas())

popUpMenu.ShowAtPosition(*Expect mouse position here*)
popUpMenu.Show()
```

I would expect to put in the mouse position as a Fyne Position at the mentioned position. But I don't know where I can get the mouse/cursor position from.

This way the popup is always stuck to the top left of the app.

Comment: If you want to display the popup in response to a mouse event (e.g. clicked or tapped), the event gives access to the even location (where you clicked or tapped).

Comment: Can you give me an example with code? A button callback function for example has no function parameters I could use.

Comment: You could extend `Button` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691001/failing-at-extending-fynes-widgets) how) and [`Button.Tapped()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.0.0/widget#Button.Tapped) directly receives the position as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PointEvent` is passed into the methods that implement interfaces to do with interaction. Button `OnTapped` hides these details as they are not normally needed.

As suggested in some comments, you should extend the widget you want to respond to this like the button in fyne_demo does around this line: https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/blob/c29a0624ed96ba1b8f45d903b6941824d50e0502/cmd/fyne_demo/tutorials/widget.go#L359

Implementing `Tapped(e *fyne.PointEvent)` is the key.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out later this week.